# Defer, Async and the PageSpeed Insights

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous

I try to optimize the page speed load using the recommendations of PageSpeed Insights about, particularly, the deferring JavaScripts, in order do not block the page content to render.

So, it appears that HTML5 introduced a preatty cool feature, the `async` attribute, that permits to load scripts asynchronously in the "chaotic" mode. There is another attribute, the `defer` one, that loads them also asynchronously, but in the "ordered" mode (as I understood from [that article](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-async)).

So, I concluded that

1. **Always** use (for every `<script src='my.js'>`) the `defer` attribute.
2. In case if the script is not "load critical" (like jQuery, or jQuery-ui) the `async` attribute can be used.

Is it the right conclusion ?

PS.

Complimentary question:
Is the fact of adding scripts **at the end of the document**, automatically "unblocks" the rendering of the document? As I could understand, some scripts blocks the rendering, without difference of their location in the document (the `<head>` or just before `</body>`)...

Comment: Why wouldn't jQuery be "load critical", if you use `$` and it's not loaded, it would seem rather critical to me ?

Comment: load critical, like jQuery :)

Comment: @serhio I read that as "not load critical, like jquery"

Comment: Oh okay, misread that then?  Why not just add the scripts in the right order just before `</body>`, problem solved ?

Comment: Defer can be used to pervent the page load blocking when the script is beign downloaded, that's the right approach. Personally i think you should only use async for scripts that add features to the page when it's already loaded, but never us it on a script that's needed by other scripts to run. Also note that not every browser supports this features.

Comment: @serhio If possible, please clarify requirement ? a) Load (script) elements into document in synchronous order ? b) Load (script) elements into in asynchronous order ? c) Both a) & b), depending on script ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Always use (for every `<script src='my.js'>`) the defer attribute.

You should only defer scripts that can be deferred. In some cases you may need to guarantee execution order, or rely on features that must happen inline. For example, scripts that call `document.write` **must not** be deferred.

> 2.  In case if the script is not "load critical" (like jQuery, or jQuery-ui) the `async` attribute can be used.

"load critical" doesn't have any specific meaning, so it's a poor choice of phrasing. `async` should be used for scripts that can execute in any order and aren't a dependency of other scripts.

Comment: as I understood, 'defer' guarantees the execution order "between the diferred scripts"... I agree that if it's an "explicitly inline" script defer should not be used... but sometimes is hard to know it apriori...

Comment: @serhio, what i meant by "guarantee execution order" is that a script could rely on the state of the DOM before the DOM has finished loading. Even though other scripts would be executed in the same order the DOM would be in a different state due to the deferment.

Comment: The defer scripts are guaranteed to be executed in the order they occur in the page. That execution starts after parsing is completely finished, but before the document’s DOMContentLoaded event. as in https://www.webkit.org/blog/1395/running-scripts-in-webkit/

Comment: fortunately, there is quite a bit scripts that uses document.write (at least in my projects). But the jQuery, can I use with defer?